# BlueRay disc reader failed to disengage, how to fix

Tags: magnet

I got a BlueRay disk player which is failing to a very stupid mechanical defect. The spin head below this cover is magnetized and when the drive is closed it will raise and slot in the disc in the hole in the middle of the disc, then the small piece of metal will be suck downwards by the magnet to hold firm the disc. However when the drive is not loaded, when I try to eject the tray, I saw the spin head try to lower itself, however it seems the magnet is too strong and the upper plastic piece holding the metal also bends downward to go with the spin head, thus the mechanism is not lowered thus the tray cannot eject.

should this problem be fixed by one of the following?

1. adding spacer between the plastic piece and the tray to increase distance between magnet and metal piece
2. somehow stiffen the plastic piece
3. get a stronger motor for the eject mechanism so that it has enough force to pull down the spin head

I am sorry this does not seem too electrical, but I cannot find another more appropriate stack, kindly tell me if you see one.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did that get past testing? Can't you just talk to Phillips?

Comment: the top bracket is not supposed to bend ... when the tray is closed, it should lower so that the metal disk touches the spindle ... the bracket should not touch the disk when the tray is closed

Comment: first i would do a test ... use something like a chopstick .... lay it across the length of the top bracket from one mounting screw to the other mounting screw... use nylon cable ties to attach the chopstick on either side of the metal disk ... that would tell me if a stiffening rod would solve the issue of the bracket being too flexible

Comment: it is quite possible that some part of the mechanism is in the wrong position ... the top bracket should not have to be forced down against the spindle

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has almost nothing to do with Electrical Engineering.